# Dual 4k monitor setup at 60hz with 2015(?) 15" MacBook Pro

Tags: display, hardware

I purchased the 15 inch MacBook Pro that costs $1999 on Apple's website a couple of weeks ago. I believe this is the 2015 model, and it does not have a touchbar.

I have been using the laptop itself for a while, and I'm ready to get a dual monitor setup for productivity purposes. I specifically wanted a monitor that would be very similar to the retina quality of the laptop's screen, so I went for the most pixel dense option I could find under $500, and this meant going for a 24 inch 4k. I picked the [Dell P2415Q](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00PC9HFNY).

First and foremost, will I have any issues running this monitor at 60hz? Second, how could I go about using two of these at 60hz? If I like this one, I'm going to order a second one.

Thanks in advance for your help. I just switched to Mac after years of using Windows/Linux on a 5k gaming PC I built four years ago, so I'm not used to having to consider these sorts of questions.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to run two 4K monitors at 60hz. However, you'll probably be stuck at 30hz if you are using HDMi. If it is in fact a 2015 MBP, there should be a few thunderbolt 2 ports. I'd suggest using a mini display port -> display port cable that supports Display Port 1.2 and thunderbolt 2. Something like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00A7R9I22) should do the job. Also, since I don't know the exact model you have, I'd hold off on buying the second monitor until you know what your MBP is fully capable of.